# gsub in awk with variable

Tags: linux, awk, gsub

I want to replace the ">" with variable names staring with ">" and ends with ".". But the following code is not printing the variable names.

```
for f in *.fasta; 
do  
nam=$(basename $f .fasta);
awk '{print $f}' $f | awk '{gsub(">", ">$nam."); print $0}'; done
```

Input of first file `sample01.fasta`:

cat `sample01.fasta`:

```
 >textofDNA
 ATCCCCGGG
 >textofDNA2
 ATCCCCGGGTTTT
```

Output expected:

```
 >sample01.textofDNA
 ATCCCCGGG
 >sample01.textofDNA2
 ATCCCCGGGTTTT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or like this?  You don't really need the looping and basename or two awk invocations.

```
awk '{stub=gensub( /^([^.]+\.)fasta.*/ , "\\1", "1",FILENAME ) ; gsub( />/, ">"stub); print}' *.fasta 
 >sample01.textofDNA
 ATCCCCGGG
 >sample01.textofDNA2
 ATCCCCGGGTTTT
```

Explanation:  `awk` has knowledge of the filename it currently operates on through the built-in variable `FILENAME`;  I strip the `.fasta` extension using gensub, and store it in the variable stub.  The I invoke gsub to replace ">" with ">" and the content of my variable `stub`. After that I print it.

As Ed points out in the comments: `gensub` is a GNU extension and won't work on other awk implementations.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks! 

Might be better if you kindly explain the code.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{fname=FILENAME; sub(/[^.]+$/,"",fname)} sub(/^>/,""){$0=">" fname $0} 1' *.fasta
>sample01.textofDNA
ATCCCCGGG
>sample01.textofDNA2
ATCCCCGGGTTTT
```

Compared to the other answers you've got so far, the above will work in any awk, only does the file name calculation once per input file rather than once per line or once per `>`-line, won't fail if the file name contains other `.`s, won't fail if the file name contains `&`, and won't fail if the file name doesn't contain the string `fasta`..

Comment: Plus one for the one time filename evaluation :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following too.

```
awk '/^>/{split(FILENAME,array,".");print substr($0,1,1) array[1]"." substr($0,2);next} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk '
/^>/{                                            ##Checking condition if a line starts from > then do following.
  split(FILENAME,array,".")                      ##Using split function of awk to split Input_file name here which is stored in awk variable FILENAME.
  print substr($0,1,1) array[1]"." substr($0,2)  ##Printing substring to print 1st char then array 1st element and then substring from 2nd char to till last of line.
  next                                           ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                                                ##1 will print all lines(except line that are starting from >).
' sample01.fasta                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```